# Move objects in array where duplicates occur

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects, each array has a key of name and then another array of objects:

```
const myArray = [ { name: "1", item: [{}] }, { name: "2", item: [{}] }, { name: "1", item: [{}] } ]
```

Now for example sometimes that name key will be the same, i want to be able to check if that name exists and if it does exist push the item into that array object and not into a new object.

The behaviour im getting is above but i would like:

```
const myArray = [ { name: "1", item: [{ item1, item2 etc }] }, { name: "2", item: [{}] }, { name: "3", item: [{}] } ]
```

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Does item array also contain an object inside array? or is it like `item: [item1, item2]`?

Comment: Thanks for replying, yes so item can be: item: [ item1: {}, item2: {}]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the desired result using [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), grouping by `name`.

If two objects in `myArray` share the same name, the item values are combined.

```js
const myArray = [ { name: "1", item: [{ id: 1 }] }, { name: "2", item: [{ id: 2}] }, { name: "1", item: [{ id: 3}] } ]

const result = Object.values(myArray.reduce((acc, { name, item }) => { 
    acc[name] = acc[name] || { name, item: [] };
    acc[name].item.push(...item);
    return acc;
}, {}))

console.log('Result:', result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using `Array.prototype.reduce` function.

```js
const myArray = [ { name: "1", item: [{}] }, { name: "2", item: [{}] }, { name: "1", item: [{}] } ];

const output = myArray.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const index = acc.findIndex(pre => pre.name === curr.name);
  if(index !== -1) {
    acc[index].item = acc[index].item.concat(curr.item);
  } else {
    acc.push(curr);
  }
  
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(output);
```